# i want to take some html ,javascript design from one website by right click 'inspect element'?

Tags: javascript, html

When i right click 'inspect element' options is not appearing,instead of that below options are appearing

setting,
global settings,
adobe flash player.
by clicking these 3 options it is going to adobe flash player home page.how i can get inspect element.please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking over a flash element. Just use `F12` on your keyboard to get the browser inspector. This will open up another window with devtools.

Comment: yes it is flash player only,when i use F12 same options are showing,i tried ctrl+shift+i also,but its not working.

Comment: you cannot inspect a flash element! you just have the flash element added to the html! If the web site is only built with flash, then there is very little to be inspected and fixed.

Comment: if heard  flashfirebug is used  for debugging flash elements.is it true